# Waiting for IE's "This page can't be displayed" Page

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create an explicit wait with Selenium that waits for the visibility of the "This page can't be displayed" message in Internet Explorer when a page cannot be reached.  Selenium, of course, has a problem with the apostrophe in xpaths.  The code I'm working with is the following ...

```
String expectedText = "This page can't be displayed";
String waitforXpath = "//div[contains(.,'"+expectedText+"')]";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(waitforXpath)));
```

But of course, Selenium throws a TimeoutException waiting on the visibility of the "This page can't be displayed" element.  Any suggestions as to how to best work around this?

**EDIT:**  Here is the source for that page ...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="NewErrorPageTemplate.css" >

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>This page can't be displayed</title>

    <script src="errorPageStrings.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script src="httpErrorPagesScripts.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
</head>

<body onLoad="javascript:getInfo();">
    <div id="contentContainer" class ="mainContent">
        <div id="mainTitle" class="title">This page can't be displayed</div>
        <div class="taskSection" id="taskSection">
            <ul id="cantDisplayTasks" class="tasks">
                <li id="task1-1">Make sure the web address <span id="webpage" class="webpageURL"></span>is correct.</li>
                <li id="task1-2">Look for the page with your search engine.</li>
                <li id="task1-3">Refresh the page in a few minutes.</li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="notConnectedTasks" class="tasks" style="display:none">
                <li id="task2-1">Check that all network cables are plugged in.</li>
                <li id="task2-2">Verify that airplane mode is turned off.</li>
                <li id="task2-3">Make sure your wireless switch is turned on.</li>
                <li id="task2-4">See if you can connect to mobile broadband.</li>
                <li id="task2-5">Restart your router.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div><button id="diagnose" class="diagnoseButton" onclick="javascript:diagnoseConnectionAndRefresh(); return false;">Fix connection problems</button></div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Use a different XPath, CSS, or anything else ... all of which we cannot help you with, without seeing the relevant part of the HTML.

Comment: Did you try using ID, `By.Id("mainTitle")` ?

Comment: @Sham I'd ideally like to specify the "This page can't be displayed" message, since any page could have an element with an ID of `mainTitle` that doesn't necessarily say "This page can't be displayed"

Comment: True, why don't you get the element ans check the text of it!

Comment: @Sham how would you incorporate that into a WebDriver wait like I am trying to do?

Comment: Can you try `ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.id("mainTitle"), "This page can't be displayed"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that Selenium actually couldn't find any elements on IE's "This page can't be displayed" page, but it could on any other page.  It was also able to find elements on Firefox's and Chrome's respective "Problem loading page" pages.  It could, however, get the title of the page in IE which is equal to the text of the `mainTitle` WebElement I was looking for, originally.  So I resorted to the following solution ...

```
expectedText = "This page can't be displayed";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driverRp,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.titleContains(expectedText));
```

I've changed the title of my question to reflect the actual root of the problem I was having, since the underlying problem is different from what I expected and originally asked about.  Very strange behavior in this IE/Selenium interaction.  I don't know why it can't find WebElements on the "This page can't be displayed" page.  Comment if anyone knows!

Answer (score 0):

You can greatly simplify your problem by checking for the text like so:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.id("mainTitle"), "This page can't be displayed"));
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working.  Still won't find the element.

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be working." is not really explicit. Have a read through https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It still throws a TimeoutException ... `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for text ('This page can't be displayed') to be present in element found by By.id: mainTitle`

Comment: Yeah I've tried timeouts up to 60 seconds and still the same exception is thrown.

Comment: Just for kicks and giggles, try a timeout like `10000`, to see if it *ever* comes up.

Comment: Ha, alright I'll try 600 first and let you know what happens.

Comment: Still throws the same exception; I also tried escaping the single quote with a backslash and that also yielded the same failed results.

Comment: At this point I feel like this is a game of 21 questions. The only thing I can suggest is to read through: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try this for loop logic. The code would get the title of the page after waiting for 2 seconds and retry it again 5 times.

```
boolean isTitleFound= false;
int tryCount = 0;
while (!isTitleFound || (tryCount++)<5)

    try{
        Thread.sleep(2000)
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

    if (driver.getTitle().equalsIgnoreCase("This page can't be displayed") {
        isTitleFound = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I considered going about it this way, but I really wanted to try and get it working with the WebDriverWait and ExpectedConditions classes if possible because that's what they're there for, after all.  This might be the only way to crack it though.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you are passing a value into an xpath query you will have to handle any apostrophe in that value. The actual xpath query you are trying to run is;

```
//div[contains(.,'This page can't be displayed')]
```

You'd think you would be able to escape it but others and I have had problems doing that in the past.

http://www.seleniumtests.com/2010/08/xpath-and-single-quotes.html

Using concat works for me and the person in the above link.I'd expect the following xpath to work.

```
String expectedText = "concat('This page can','\"'\"','t be displayed')";
String waitforXpath = "//div[contains(.,'"+expectedText+"')]";
```

In general I tend to pass any values i'm inserting into xpath through a method that will turn it into an xpath ready concat string. This is c#.

```
private string prepareForXpath(string text)
{
    if (!text.Contains("'"))
    {
        return "'" + text + "'";
    }
    StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();
    finalString.Append("concat('");
    finalString.Append(text.Replace("'", "',\"'\",'"));
    finalString.Append("')");
    return finalString.ToString();        
}
```

This can all be quite messy and it's why xpath locators can be a pain. I'd prefer the method suggested by SiKing. The fact that approach isn't working probably deserves more investigation.